# Can't access my hard drives

Tags: partitioning

I am currently running Ubuntu with Kubuntu installed.

I have 3 SSD and 1 HDD

I can use my system SSD where the OS is running, but my other 3 drives are locked Up.

Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run these commands and paste their outputs:

ls /
ls /media
ls /mnt
cat /etc/fstab

Comment: Did you create mount points, mount partitions to those mount points & give yourself ownership & permissions to use those mounted partitions. I also like to label all partitions, so if not auto mounted in fstab, then a manual mount uses label not UUID. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting